# Rogue 'Pages' link in new experience left nav

Tags: sharepoint-online, new-experience

I've noticed recently that a new link is showing up from nowhere in the left nav of new UX pages. Are we stuck with this for the time being, or does anyone have a workaround?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the new experience ? Or do you want to remove pages from new experience ?

Comment: I personally don't care, I'm just anticipating this becoming an issue with a customer of mine :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are stuck with this for the time being. Checked in my tenant and the link is showing up as well. Unfortunately, we can't do any modifications as the customizations are disabled on the "Modern" experiences.

Check this user voice request - [Allow Javascript customization and CSS branding/theming in the new Document Library Experience](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13385364-allow-javascript-customization-and-css-branding-th)

Workaround - switch back to the classic mode, by clicking on the "Return to classic SharePoint" as below:

[image]

If you want everything in classic mode at tenant level, set the settings as below. Go to https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com > settings . Click on 
classic experience as below:

[image]

Also, if you want it at a specific list/library level, go the the list settings page and set the experience as Classic. Check screenshot :

[image]

Also, if you are game for CSOM programming, you can set it using the latest CSOM dll as below:

```
var lists = context.Web.Lists;
context.Load(lists, col => col.Include(l => l.ListExperienceOptions));
context.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (var list in lists)
{
    if (list.ListExperienceOptions != ListExperience.ClassicExperience)
    {
         list.ListExperienceOptions = ListExperience.ClassicExperience; 
         // list.ListExperienceOptions = ListExperience.NewExperience; 
         // list.ListExperienceOptions = ListExperience.Auto; 
         list.Update();
    }
}
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: I thought that would be the answer, I just haven't been checking to see if the ability to add customisations to the new ux has been added in yet.